# Is there an efficient way to measure the distance from a single point to every point in a large array of points?

Tags: matlab

I am writing a code that is trying to color the complex plane, such that all points exactly a distance of 1 unit from them are different colors. Comparing the distance between a large number of points takes too long for my code.

What I have tried doing so far is to create a point at the origin, then it creates a single point on the unit circle, colors it different and then moves to the next point on the unit circle. My code compares each point to every other point created by checking the distance between them to see if it's 1, and if it is, then compares the color to ensure they are different. My code works for a small number of points but gets very slow as the number of points grows (as after I complete the unit circle around the origin, I create unit circle around each point that I just created an so on). How can a cut down the number of comparisons I make?

```matlab
p=[p;p(m,1)+exp(1i*j*h),1]; % the list of points already created
l=length(p)-1; % the length for my for loop
toss=[]; % creates storage of colors already used
   for k1=1:l % checks every point previously created
       % if statement checks the distance between two point
       if abs(p(end,1)-p(k1,1))>(1-tol) & abs(p(end,1)-p(k1,1))<(1+tol)
           toss=[toss,p(k1,2)]; % adds the color of any point in a unit step
       end
   end
colornum=[1,2,3,4,5,6]; % defines colors as number
toss=unique(toss); % condenses all the colors already used
Arr3 = setxor(colornum,toss); %creates a vector of unused colors
p(end,2)=Arr3(1); % assigns the first available color
```

I would like for the output to be a large matrix with the first column being the position in the complex plane and the second column being the number corresponding to a color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slowing is probably because of the loop and if statement.

Try to vectorize it :

```
point_to_compare = p(end,1);
vec_to_compare = p(1:end-1,1);
points_to_add = [abs(abs(vec_to_compare - point_to_compare)-1)<tol; false];
toss = p(points_to_add,2);
```

Comment: That works considerably faster! Side note if anyone is reading the solution and is interested, the vec_to_compare needs to be transposed to be compared. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: Great! I fixed the vector dimensions.